# What exactly is "the cloud"

Tags: networking, internet, storage, cloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is cloud computing?](https://superuser.com/questions/1940/what-is-cloud-computing)

What exactly is "the cloud"? According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing), the source of all knowledge, cloud computing is

> the use of computing resources (hardware and software) that are
> delivered as a service over a network (typically the Internet).

So basically it's just a marketing gimick because one could just as easly say, for example, backup the files to the network OR backup settings to the internet?

Comment: "marketing gimick"? Yes, absolutely, the term has been abused for quite some time now. [What is Cloud Computing and What Does This Stupid Buzzword Mean? - How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32016/what-is-cloud-computing-and-what-does-this-stupid-buzzword-mean/)

Comment: I've got to say at a university I took a course on networking and the prof came in every morning and drew a diagram of a network and called it "a cloud"

Comment: That's what it's come down to, yeah. Anything remotely related to networks and the Internet is called "cloud" these days.